# Obtaining Weather Data From NOAA

Tags: weather, noaa

I am trying to use the API to return data from the Chagrin Falls station in Ohio. I can get the data from the website so I know there is data, but the API does not return any values.

I have a valid token and the examples in the documentation work, but if I try any to alter the examples in any way I get nothing back just any empty json object {}.

Example I am trying to use:
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GSOM&stationid=GHCND:US1OHGG0014&units=standard&startdate=2020-08-01&enddate=2020-08-01&limit=1000

Data from the website:
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datasets/GHCND/stations/GHCND:US1OHGG0014/detail

Comment: What sort of data are you looking for? I use api.weather.gov  - it has all conditions, forecasts, warnings, etc.

Comment: I'm looking for daily precipitation totals for a given city.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how you are going to achieve this since you haven't told us what programming language you are using. However, with python I use a module called urllib to extract raw html data from a url that can be seen from the browser using ctrl+u.

Comment: I am making the call using postman to just see what data comes back. I am not calling anything from code yet.

Comment: Ah, then I was mistaken.